# UnauthorizedBlobOverwrite : Azure logic apps is throwing exception

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-lake

I am retrieving the file from the `shared point` with the help of a Azure logic apps and dumping into the Azure ADLS (gen2) but if the ADLS already has the file with the same name then it is throwing the exception 'UnauthorizedBlobOverwrite'.
So my question is- `How do I overwrite into the ADLS layer`.
Please note I am using the HTTP trigger to dump the data into the ADLS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that we have the adequate permission on the ADLS gen2 .

Can you please the status code ?  i am assuming its 403 , if that's the case can you please check if you are trying https://your_account.blob.core.windows.net  please try to use
https://your_account.dfs.core.windows.net – and it should work

Comment: updated the url to `https://your_account.dfs.core.windows.net ` but got the `401` error. Status code: 401

"error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationInfo",
    "message": "Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.\nRequestId:XXXXX-601f-0065-XXXX-7XXXXX000000\nTime:2020-08-27T11:53:06.1799620Z"
  }

Comment: I mean.. this time it did not copy the file to adls and thrown the exception.